# How to estimate the maximum of a probability density function using sample points?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, physics, python

I have an experiment that shoots particles at a wall. It hits some regions with a higher probability than others. I don't know what the underlying probability density function is. I assume it's some smooth curve and I would like to know its maximum value.

I can get an estimate by firing lots of particles and recording where they land. Then make a histogram of the data and calculate the maximum value from that. The problem is I don't know what the optimum number of bins to use for the histogram is. Additionally, I don't know how accurate my estimate is. Do you know if there is a formula or method I can use to calculate the optimum number of bins for a given number of samples? Do you know if we can approximate error bars for our estimate?

I have attached some Python code to help explain what I am doing. In this example, the underlying probability density function is the normal distribution, with mean, $\mu=0$, and variance $\sigma^2=1$. In this example, I know the exact solution is $1/\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}$, however, in general, I don't know the formula for the probability density function so we need to estimate its maximum.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu = 0
sigma = 1
len_particles_array = 5
num_particles_array = 10**np.arange(1, len_particles_array + 1)

len_bin_array = 16
num_bins_array = 2**np.arange(len_bin_array)

max_number_density_array = np.zeros((len_particles_array, len_bin_array))

analytic_solution = 1 / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * sigma**2)

for i, num_particles in enumerate(num_particles_array):
    particle_positions = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, num_particles)
    for j, num_bins in enumerate(num_bins_array):
        number_density, bins = np.histogram(particle_positions, num_bins, density=True)
        max_number_density_array[i, j] = np.max(number_density)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for i, num_particles in enumerate(num_particles_array):
    ax.loglog(num_bins_array, max_number_density_array[i, :], \
              label = '# particles = ' + str(num_particles))

xlims = ax.get_xlim()
ax.loglog(xlims, [analytic_solution, analytic_solution], 'k--', \
          label = r'Exact solution = $1\ /\ \sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}$')
ax.set_xlim(xlims)

ax.set_xlabel('Number of bins')
ax.set_ylabel('Estimate for the maximum of the probability density function')
ax.legend()

plt.savefig('Estimate for the maximum of the probability density function.png')

plt.show()
```

Here is the outputted figure. It shows the estimate is dependent on the number of bins I use for the histogram and the number of sample particles I use.
[image]

Comment: Nice exploration and graph! (+1) Notice that for $n = 1000$ you get best results from histograms with about 20 bins. This agrees with part of my Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, it seems you don't want the *mode,* which is the $x$-value at which the density $f(x)$ reaches its maximum; you want $\max_{x \in R}f(x),$ where $R$ is the  real line. Using the standard normal distribution as an example, you want $\varphi(0) = 1/\sqrt{2\pi} = 0.3989 \approx  0.4,$ where $\varphi$ denotes the standard normal density function.

In R software, $\varphi$ is `dnorm`; default parameters are $\mu=0, \sigma=1:$

```
dnorm(0)
[1] 0.3989423
```

If, you have the density function, you can often use
methods of calculus to find the maximum value of a
a function.

If you have data generated from a distribution and
do not know the density function of the distribution,
you might come close by trying histograms, as you
suggest. That will work best if you have a large
sample. A difficulty is that choice of bins (intervals)
for a histogram is arbitrary, so different histograms
will typically have various tallest bars of various heights.

Let's look at a sample of size $n = 1000$ from
the distribution $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0, \sigma=2),$
for which the desired max is known to be $0.1995,$
to four places.

```
dnorm(0, 0, 2)
[1] 0.1994711    # max height of std norm density

set.seed(2021)
x = rnorm(1000)  # sample of 1000
```

Specifically, if you have data (1000 observations), but you don't know from what
continuous distribution they were sampled, then you might look at histograms similar to the ones shown below.

I have cheated by plotting the density curve,
which we're pretending is unknown, on each histogram.
You can see that some histograms work better than
others for guessing the maximum height of the density
curve. [R code (tediously repetitive) for the figure is shown at the end.]

[image]

However, kernel density estimators (KDEs) provide a
somewhat more useful path. A KDE is the density of a mixture of
distributions from a suitable family, that approximates the population density using a sample from that distribution.
(For more on KDEs, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_estimation). For R documentation on `density`, see [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/density). Also, there are some pages on this site that discuss the convergence of KDEs to their target PDFs, with varying degrees of formality; type `KDE` after the 'magnifying glass' at the top of the page to get a list.
(All give insights into KDEs, but I don't see that any deal directly with
your question of finding the maximum.)

In R, a KDE consists of 512 $(x,y)$ pairs that can
be connected by short line segments to show an estimate
of the desired density curve. There are many possible
variations of the KDEs in R, but I have chosen to
use the default KDE, which I have found works very
well in most cases. Here is text output from the `density` procedure in R.

```
density(x)

Call:
        density.default(x = x)

Data: x (1000 obs.);    Bandwidth 'bw' = 0.4608

       x                 y            
 Min.   :-7.7861   Min.   :9.830e-06  
 1st Qu.:-3.7491   1st Qu.:2.834e-03  
 Median : 0.2879   Median :3.034e-02  
 Mean   : 0.2879   Mean   :6.187e-02  
 3rd Qu.: 4.3248   3rd Qu.:1.242e-01  
 Max.   : 8.3618   Max.   :1.951e-01
```

Notice that the maximum height (y-coordinate)
of the KDE) is $0.1951,$ which is very close
to the actual maximum height $0.1995$ of
the density function of $\mathsf{Norm}(0, 2).$

Here is the default histogram of the values in `x`,
along with this actual density function (black) along with
its KDE (red) based on my sample of size $n = 1000.$

[image]

```
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 curve(dnorm(x,0,2), add=T)
 lines(density(x), col="red")
```

*Notes:* (1) If I wanted to know the 'mode' (the x-value
at which the y-value is maximized, I could do a
grid search for it, as below. The result is that
the mode of the KDE is a $0.209 \approx 0.$

```
vert = density(x)$y; max.vert=max(vert); max.vert
[1] 0.1950648
horz = density(x)$x
mean(horz[vert==max.vert])
[1] 0.2088506
```

(2) Comparisons: (a) If we have $n=1000$ observations `x` *known to have been
randomly sampled from some normal distribution,* then we should
be able to estimate the maximum height by using `dnorm` in R,
with the sample mean $\bar X$ estimating $\mu$ and the sample SD $S$
estimating $\sigma.$ For the sample `x` above, this method gives
the maximum height as $0.1957.$

(b) This is not much different
from the result $0.1951$ above from the KDE. Above, the KDE method
uses normal data, but does not explicitly assume normality.

(c) Also, from above we know that a histogram with about 20 bins (lower left in first figure) has its tallest bar near the max. This information can
be displayed by using densities from a non-printing histogram (argument `plot=F`); the result is $2.0.$  This method does not assume normality,
but may require some trial and error with histograms that have various numbers of bins. (In a real application, you wouldn't have the actual density curve in the background to guide you.)

```
dnorm(0, mean(x), sd(x))
[1] 0.1956927    # (a) Known normal, estimate mean and SD

max(density(x)$y)
[1] 0.1950648    # (b) Default KDE in R

max(hist(x, br=20, plot=F)$density)
[1] 0.2          # (c) Carefully chosen histogram
```

---

```
# R code for first figure
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
 hist(x, prob=T, br=5, ylim=c(0,.2), col="skyblue2")
  curve(dnorm(x,0,2), ylim=c(0,.2), add=T)
  abline(h=.2, col="red")
 hist(x, prob=T, br=10, col="skyblue2")
  curve(dnorm(x,0,2), add=T)
  abline(h=.2, col="red")
 hist(x, prob=T, br=20, col="skyblue2")
  abline(h=.2, col="red")
  curve(dnorm(x,0,2), add=T)
 hist(x, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2")
  abline(h=.2, col="red")
  curve(dnorm(x,0,2), add=T)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. KDE's do indeed look like the solution to my problem.